# iMessage App: Sticker from ImageFile from disk can be peeled of, but not placed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

My standalone Message App saves images like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"]];
```

The PNG files are than loaded into MSStickers and correctly displayed in a MSStickerBrowserView. When I try to place the sticker in a conversation, the sticker disappears after a second. It works fine with my test image inside the Resources folder:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
```

Does anyone know what kind of problem this is? There is no error message either.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer: The saved image files where larger than allowed. After shrinking it works